# Screen Navigation doesnt work with Params React Navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have this coding in my inside page of my app

screeen 3 from where i want to click on wifi list item which should then open the Wifi screen

Screen 3 is a screen from Tab navigator which is activated after the auth layout with stack navigatoin

my coding is as below

screenthree.js

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { 
    View,
    
    StyleSheet
    } from "react-native";
import { Container, Header, Content, List, ListItem, Text, Icon, Left, Body, Right, Switch } from 'native-base';

class ScreenThree extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <Container>
       
        <Content>
          <List>
            
            <ListItem icon onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('WifiScreen', {
              itemId: 86,
              otherParam: 'anything you want here',
            })}>
              <Left>
                <Icon name="wifi" />
              </Left>
              <Body>
                <Text>Wi-Fi</Text>
              </Body>
              <Right>
                <Text>GeekyAnts</Text>
                <Icon name="arrow-forward" />
              </Right>
            </ListItem>
          </List>
        </Content>
      </Container>  
        );
    }
}
export default ScreenThree;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
    flex:1,
    alignItems:'center',
    justifyContent:'center'
    }
});
```

and coding for the wifi screen is as below

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { 
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet
    } from "react-native";

    
    // const itemId = this.props.navigation.getParam('itemId', 'NO-ID');
    // const otherParam = this.props.navigation.getParam('otherParam', 'some default value');

class WifiScreen extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>WifiScreen</Text>
                {/* <Text>itemId: {JSON.stringify(itemId)}</Text>
        <Text>otherParam: {JSON.stringify(otherParam)}</Text> */}
            </View>
        );
    }
}
export default WifiScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
    flex:1,
    alignItems:'center',
    justifyContent:'center'
    }
});
```

Now everything is working fine and wifi screen is opening when I click on wifi list item unless I uncomment the param coding from wifi.js

after uncommenting that I am getting `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')` error

dependencies : 
"expo": "^28.0.0",
    "native-base": "^2.6.1",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-28.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.13",
    "react-navigation": "2.0.1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get params outside of the class `WifiScreen`. thats why its getting error. You should get the params from within the class. like the following.

```
class WifiScreen extends Component{
    render(){
        const {itemId, otherParam} = this.props.navigation.state.params;
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>WifiScreen</Text>
                <Text>itemId: {JSON.stringify(itemId)}</Text>
                <Text>otherParam: {JSON.stringify(otherParam)}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to use the **params** in some function invoked not in the Render method, where I can define the const {params}= this.props.navigation.state.params;